# Rxjs: Is there any operator in rxjs which can execute when the array is not mapped?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a static array of

```
var array=[{name:'test',id:2106},{name:'test2',id:2107},{name:'test3',id:2108}];

I have a selected name
var selName='test4';
```

I would like to execute function when the selName does not match with any of the name in objects of array.

let function be

```
function runtesting(){

}
```

If selName matches the name in array I would like to show an alert box.

How can we achieve this using Rxjs operators?

Comment: This doesn't look like a great example to use rxjs.... Can't see any stream. And if selName is a stream, then `selNameStream.subscribe(s => if([s is in array]){ showAlertBox(); }else{ runTesting(); }`

Comment: Its not a stream, I would like to use rxjs because the below functions are triggering asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

```
const array$ = Observable.of([
 {name:'test', id:2106},
 {name:'test2', id:2107},
 {name:'test3', id:2108}
])

const selectedName$ = new BehaviorSubject('test4')
```

Then just combine both:

```
const runTestingSub = Observable
  .combineLatest(array$, selectedName$)
  .map(([arr, name]) => !arr.some(item => item.name === name))
  .filter(Boolean) // Emit only if there is no name in array
  .subscribe(runTesting) // runTesting runs only if there is no obj with name
```

You can even make it more performant by storing this array as key-value construction like:

```
{
   test: { name: 'test', id: 2106 },
   test2: { name: 'test2', id: 2107 }
}
```

Or even JavaScript/Immutable `Map`. For example:

```
const arrayReduced$ = Observable
  .of([
     {name:'test', id:2106},
     {name:'test2', id:2107},
     {name:'test3', id:2108}
  ])
  .scan((acc, curr) => Object.assign({}, acc, {
    [curr.name]: curr
  }), {})
```

Then `runTestingSub` will look like this:

```
const runTestingSub = Observable
  .combineLatest(array$, selectedName$)
  .map(([keyValueObj, name]) => !keyValueObj[name])
  .filter(Boolean)
  .subscribe(runTesting)
```